# Diretorio / Alias com domínio

Tags: php, wordpress, alias

Olá, tenho um dominio http://www.~dominio.com.br/novo

Quero fazer com que quando entrar no http://www.~dominio.com.br redirecione para o /novo e não apareça na url que está em novo, tem algo que eu psosa fazer no php, como *phpengine*, rule ?

O problema é que nao consegui migrar um wordpress que está em /novo que buga toda página, então quero migrar ele pelo nome no domínio (gambiarra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se isso te ajuda...

Passo 1 – O painel.
Acesse o painel do WordPress em sua conta. Procure pelo menu do lado esquerdo, onde está escrito "Configurações".
Vá em "Endereço do Blog (URL)" onde vc pode determinar como queremos abrir o blog, qual será o endereço principal a ser usado para acessar suas páginas. Acima você usa sempre o endereço do diretório para acessar sua conta, mas embaixo pode escolher o domínio principal.
Assim, onde está "Endereço do blog (URL)" deixe apenas o endereço principal. Role a página e salve as mudanças.

Passo 2 – Modificando o arquivo Index.PHP
Vai ficar um pouco mais complicado agora. Na pasta "wordpress" que você instalou em seu serviço de hospedagem, há um arquivo chamado "INDEX.PHP. Pode até ser que você o tenha em backup no seu PC. Salve-o e abra no Bloco de Notas para ver o código-fonte.
Tem uma linha la que esta assim : require('./wp-blog-header.php');
Troque ela por : require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
Salve com o mesmo nome substituindo o arquivo antigo. Volte ao diretório da hospedagem e faça o upload desse arquivo fora da pasta "wordpress", na pasta pública, principal de seu domínio.
Pronto. Agora seu blog já está com o endereço redirecionado para a URL principal, fora do diretório.

fonte: [br.forums.wordpress.org](https://br.forums.wordpress.org/topic/instalo-o-wordpress-na-rais-do-site-ou-dentro-de-uma-pasta)